# Hacer muchas peticiones con multiprocesos en Python

Tags: python, hilos, python-requests, peticiones, pool

No soy experto en python pero hace poco tiempo lo empecé a probar y realicé unos scripts para mi. Pero ahora me surgio una gran duda.

Describo el script que es lo que hace:

- Yo coloco una URL, esa url internamente tiene siempre muchas url adentro, puede varias, pueden ser 100 o 3400..
- esas URLs yo hago peticiones para obtener un resultado, pero claro, el sistema va de 1 en 1, yo lo que quiero hacer es hacer ese proceso pero mas rapido, digamos que vaya de 100 en 100 analizando las URLs y no de a 1 en 1..

Lei que en python ese proceso se lo llama Threading o Hilos. Pero sinceramente no se como hacerlo. Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Bienvemido a SOes, python tiene un problema con hilos y es que no los maneja como otros lenguajes, para recrear la función de hilos deberías utilizar subprocesos

Comment: @Christian no estoy muy de acuerdo con tu respuesta. Requiere de una explicacion mejor para no caer en topicos.
Nicolas, describe mejor cuando dices que la url tiene internamente muchas url. Tengo una respuesta para ti pero necesito mas detalle

Comment: bien, es una lista m3u, que adentro contiene muchas enlaces de la misma url, digamos. Url principal http://nico:80/get.php?username=nico&password=nico2&type=m3u. y adentro contine muchos enlaces de la misma cuenta. asi, http://nico:80/nico/nico/canal1.. http://nico:80/nico/nico/canal2..http://nico:80/nico/nico/canal3. asi sucesivamente hasta puede tener como 3000 enlaces o 100.. el punto es que quiero hacer esas peticiones de 100 en 100.. mi scrip funciona bien de 1 en uno pero necesito hacerlo mas rapido con hilos, que no se como hacerlo. lei mucha info pero no se por donde empezar

Comment: Y luego, de la URL final, exactamente que haces? Descargar el fichero? Mi respuesta iba encarada en asyncio y aiohttp

Comment: no, se obtiene otra url, osea un redireccionamiento.

Comment: Alguien me puede ayudar o incidar como podria hacer?

Comment: descargas una lista de urls aqui http://nico/get.php?username=nico&password=nico2&type=m3u
De esa lista, cada una que haces? me dices que hay otras listas dentro de las listas?. A lo mejor sera mas facil que edites la pregunta incluiendo toda esa infomracion

Comment: Pongamos un ejemplo, hagamos de cuenta que la url principal es www.google.com.ar. y y descargando su contenido hay muchas url adentro, limpiando todo solo me quedo con esas urls, una abajo de la otra. Esas urls estan en la variable resultado como menciono arriba. y les hago peticiones ya que algunas de esas urls pueden tener redireccionamiento, entonces con el codigo que hice consigo esos redireccionamiento. lo que necesito es hacer ese proceso pero con mas velocidad, que haga el scaneo de 100 en 100.

Comment: entendido, en breve te propongo una solucion async

Comment: gracias @gilito

Comment: @gilito Te fuiste? Alguien me puede dar una mano con este tema, Gracias

Comment: No no, aquí estoy, es que no es fácil lo que pides! Te pondré un ejemplo con threading y con asyncio. El servidor es tuyo? Lo digo para que con asyncio vas a meter muchas conneccinoes en 1 segundo

Answer (score 1):

> Te adjunto una respuesta aproximada a tu solución. El motivo de porque no puedo aproximarme mas es por el poco detalle de la pregunta. Necesitaria 5 ejemplos, por decir algo, de como son los datos que tratas, url y que haces de las respuestas cuyas necesitan mas trabajo.

Este script es un `skeleton` ideal para jugar con conceptos de `asyncronia` y `threading` y escoger la mejor forma para tu necesidad.

Tu procedimiento no requiere de mucho trabajo de `CPU` pero si de mucha espera `IO`. Por eso motivo, la arquitectura mas optima es la de `asyncio`.

Aún asi, `ASYNCIO` no dispone de un control de cola de trabajo, como si la tiene el paquete de `Threading` con `(max_workers=5)`, hay que ir con cuidado que puedes generar miles de requests a un servior en concreto en poco segundos. Debe tenerse un control del trabajo que le mandas a la CPU, por eso he adjuntado tambien la version en theading que facilmente controlas los processos `concurrentes`. No confundir `concurrentes` con `paralelos`, en `threading` no hay paralelismo debido al `GIL`.

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, aiohttp
import time,datetime
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
import requests
import re


def obtencion_lista_url_inicial():
    ### Descargar primer fichero donde hay lista de URL
    # nico:80/get.php?username=nico&password=nico2&type=m3u.
    data = requests.get('http://nico:80/get.php?username=nico&password=nico2&type=m3u.')
    if data.status_code != 200:
        print('No he podido descargar el fichero origen de las urls')
        return False
    # Las direcciones deben tener protocolo adelante, en caso de que las URL ya vengan con http a delante, substituyr por el siguiente:
    # return data.text.splitlines()
    return [f'http://{i}' for i in data.text.splitlines()]



async def fetch_aio(url):
    # print(f'Connecting {url} - {datetime.datetime.now().time()}')
    try:
        async with aiohttp.request('GET', url, raise_for_status=False,
                                   timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=4,
                                                                 connect=2,
                                                                 sock_connect=2,
                                                                 sock_read=3)) as resp:

            await resp.text()
            return url, True
    except Exception as e:
        return f'false {url} '



def fetch(url):
    #print(f'trying {url}')
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=3)
        return r, True
    except Exception as e:
        return url, False

def trabajo_asyncio():
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    urls_list = obtencion_lista_url_inicial()
    if not urls_list:
        return False
    # Creamos todo el trabajo a realizar
    request_work = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_aio(i)) for i in urls_list]
    # A trabajar!
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*request_work))
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    print(responses)

def trabajo_con_threads():
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    urls_list = obtencion_lista_url_inicial()
    if not urls_list:
        return False
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future = {executor.submit(fetch, url): url for url in urls_list}
        for future in as_completed(future):
            data = future.result()
            print(data)
```

El punto de entrada será:

- `trabajo_con_threads()`  para arquitectura con `Threading`
- `trabajo_asyncio()` para arquitectura con `Asyncio`

Debes tunear a tu gusto:

- utilizar `print(datetime.datatime.now().time()) si quieres hacer un poco de debug para ver como se van ejecutando los procesos en el tiempo
- tunear `obtencion_lista_url_inical()` si no se ajusta a tu necesidad
- tunear los timeouts, he puesto unos muy genericos,
- tunear las excepiones
- tunear las respuestas, exactamente no tengo claro que `data` necesitas de las peticiones. Basicamente tienes que adaptar los returns de las funciones

Cualquiera duda comentamos!

Comment: avisame cuando estes asi te comparto el codigo completo rapido, asi se entiende mejor. ademas en el codigo al lado de la url te coloco un ejemplo. y los resultados en verde que arroja se guardan en un text. lo que arroje en rojo no se guarda.

Comment: olvide etiquetarte @gilito

Comment: @nicolas siento no poderte aydar mas. Necesito mas detalle de tu opertiva. Este es un esqueleto basico muy interesante para enteder los conceptos de AsyncIO y Threading, si me subes com mas detalle tus origenes de datos, podre concretare mejor... se que hay redirecciones y mas detalles,que necesito ver ejemplificados...

Comment: ahi coloque el codigo completo y ademas te puse un ejemplo al lado, espero me puedas ayudar @gilito

Comment: Osea, edite el codigo al principio del post, espero se entienda con toda la info que fui brindando en los comentarios..@gilito

Comment: OK, dame un poco de tiempo, te aviso cuando lo tenga... @nicolas

Comment: okas muchas gracias @gilito

Comment: Buenas @nicolas, hay algo de trabajo adaptar tu script a un model de threading o asyncio, mas que nada porque hay que definir una funcion concreta para enviar-la en un loop o un pool... escribir en ficheros con threading es un poco complicado , vas a encontrare problemas de bloqueos, lo siento pero lo dejo, es demasiado trabajo. A lo mejor sale alguien con una recompesa... mi propuestsa de skeleton es valida, pero hay mucha distancia entre lo que has pubicado hacia el esqueleto. Te animo a seguir lidiando con ello!

Comment: muchas gracias @gilito por tu tiempo, te agradezco la predisposicion que tuviste desde el primer dia.. gracias